# How to sort result based on hit score in NEST elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST(c#) to communicate with Elasticsearch. However the results are not based on hit score, how can I sort my results based on hit score and also i am getting only 10 records. Below is my code sample

```
var result = client.Search(q => q
                               .Index(IndexName)
                               .From(0)
                               .Type("post")
                               .Fields("title","message")
                               .Size(10)
                               .Query(fq1 => fq1
                                  .QueryString(fqqs1 => fqqs1
                                    .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                                      .Add("title", 7.0)
                                      .Add("message", 5.0))
                                      .Query(SearchQuery))));
```

my `message` field  will contain large text , is it possible to get only few lines around the search keyword from the message just like google search result

Comment: As for getting a snippet of the message field, have a look at Highlighting - http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/highlighting.html

Comment: they have given what tag we can add before and after the keyword only , not about getting few line from message content , when i use `.Fields("title","message")` API return full content

Comment: Right, if you add Highlighting, the results will be in a separate `Highlights` property on the response. That will give you only a fragment of the entire field... Please see the full Highlights documentation for Elasticsearch - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html and all of these options like `.FragmentSize` can be set with NEST.

Comment: yes , you are right . i got the fragment of message field under highlights , but is it possible to get it in source field itself because i convert my result to string using
 `var jsonData = "{\"search\":[" + string.Join(",", queryResult.Documents.ToArray()) + "]}";` and i covert it into my class object using
 `var finaleResult = (client.Serializer.Deserialize<Result>(jsonData)).result` 
 so i need get highlighted content in source field itself , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 5):

Hello to sort by the hitscore just use

```
var result = client.Search(q => q
                 .Index(IndexName)
                 .From(0)
                 .Type("post")
                 .Fields("title","message")
                 .TrackScores(true)
                 .Size(10)
                 .Query(fq1 => fq1
                        .QueryString(fqqs1 => fqqs1
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                                .Add("title", 7.0)
                                .Add("message", 5.0)
                            )
                            .Query(SearchQuery)
                        )
                 .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
           );
```

To get more records just increase the number in the Size()

Comment: You can also use `sort => sort.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score)` so as not to rely on magic strings.